# Only intercept showing for coefficients in R (no sd, p, t etc)

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, coefficients

I am a stats novice. I have coded for one continuous variable (Male_Threat_Prevalence), which I know only ranges between 0-40 to be regressed using lm in R against several categorical variables I have converted to factor (Male_Age_LR + Male_Edu_LR + Male_Reg_LR)

I type:

```
Regression_PrevalenceAER <- lm(Male_Threat_PrevalenceLR ~ Male_Age_LR + Male_Edu_LR + Male_Reg_LR, 
                               data=Regression_Data, na.action = na.omit)
```

Into R and the results are:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Male_Threat_PrevalenceLR ~ Male_Age_LR + Male_Edu_LR + 
Male_Reg_LR, data = Regression_Data, na.action = na.omit)

Coefficients:
                         (Intercept)                         Male_Age_LRAge 11  
                              1.7800                                    0.9365  
                   Male_Age_LRAge 12                         Male_Age_LRAge 13  
                              1.1733                                    0.5107  
                   Male_Age_LRAge 14                         Male_Age_LRAge 15  
                              1.1562                                    0.1408  
Male_Edu_LRDoes not Attend School or Pol                       Male_Reg_LRBuddhist  
                             -0.4679                                   -1.0353  
                    Male_Reg_LRHindu                         Male_Reg_LRJewish  
                              0.1751                                   -0.9533  
                   Male_Reg_LRMuslim                          Male_Reg_LROther  
                             -0.4682                                   -0.6074  
                     Male_Reg_LRNone  
                             11.3966
```

No P value, T value or SD is shown.

I am at my wits end! please do help.

Answer (score 3):

Just one more step:

```
summary(Regression_PrevalenceAER)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ths is the code for coef.default (and there is no coef.lm, so that's what get used.

```
methods(coef)
getAnywhere(coef.default)

function (object, ...) 
object$coefficients
<bytecode: 0x7fc56176cdf0>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Then read the help page for `?lm? which says

> coefficients
>   a named vector of coefficients

So that's all you get. You were probably expecting the results of:
`coef(summary(Regression_PrevalenceAER))`. So now read the help page (*Value* section) for `?summary.lm`